# Монетизация сайта с фильмами. Какой плеер используется?

Tags: веб-программирование, плеер

Каждый видел на просмотре фильмов онлайн - рекламу, аля азино 3 топора, 1хбет и прочее, которая встраивается в плеер и показывается до просмотра.
Что это за плееры, сервисы по рекламе, как это работает? Может кто то направить на данные ресурсы?

Comment: Самописный, например?

Comment: @andreymal на многих сайтах все под копирку созданы плееры и реклама, это явно не индивидуальный подход

Comment: Ну тогда просто посмотрите название плеера в исходных кодах любого такого сайта да и всё, чего мудрить